# Using Google Analytics with FireBase + Google Tag Manager Android SDK

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase, google-tag-manager

How to fire Google Analytics tag using Firebase + Google Tag Manager SDK in Android? 
I added the Firebase container to my **assets/container** folder and created a Google Analytics tag using my GA Tracking id. I have followed exactly the steps as given in this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/#introduction

I trigger the appLaunch  event with the below code:
 
***mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("appLaunch", null);***

How can I see this in my Google Analytics report? Please correct me if am wrong. Below are the logs printed when the above code is executed.

> 05-29 04:01:19.947 10378-10419/com.aiswarya.firebase I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used 
>   05-29 04:01:19.947 10378-10419/com.aiswarya.firebase D/FA: Logging event (FE): appLaunch, Bundle[{_o=app}]
>   05-29 04:01:19.947 10378-10419/com.aiswarya.firebase V/FA: Using measurement service
>   05-29 04:01:19.947 10378-10419/com.aiswarya.firebase V/FA: Connecting to remote service
>   05-29 04:01:19.967 10378-10419/com.aiswarya.firebase D/FA: Connected to remote service
>   05-29 04:01:19.967 10378-10419/com.aiswarya.firebase V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should enable debug logging for both FirebaseAnalytics and Google Tag Manager and look at the logcat. It will likely answer your question.

You can enable Scion debug logs

```
  adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
  adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
  adb shell setprop log.tag.GoogleTagManager VERBOSE
  adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC GoogleTagManager
```

[View events in Android Studio debug log](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/cpp/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log)

TagManager is a separate library from Firebase Analytics. In order to use it in your app you need to add dependency on the tag manager form Google play services. When Firebase Analytics starts it will check for the presence of TagManager in the app and print   message in logcat. If the message print TagManager not found you don't have the TagManager in your app. When TagManager is available you will see message like "TagManager found, initializing"

Comment: Thanks djabi. I have already enabled all these logs. But only the FA logs are seen.

Comment: When Firebase Analytics starts it prints a message if it finds the TagManager in the app. If it prints "TagManager not found" you did not link to the tag manager library. Check your app/build.graddle file. TagManager is not part of the Firebase Analytics library. You need to explicitly add it as dependency.

Comment: Great, let me update the answer with the recommendation to check the dependency on the TagManager.

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager needs to be added as a separate dependency; see the documentation for doing so here:

> [Google Tag Manager for Android](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/#add-gtm-to-project)

In short:

1. Add to your module's gradle file:

   ```
   dependencies {
     // ...
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:[latest-version]'
   }
   ```
2. Download the container file and add it to `/assets/containers`.