# Android Push Notification using Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am developing an android application in which I simply want to receive push notifications in android device. I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XijS62iP1Xo&t=435s) tutorial  (Android Push Notification using Firebase Console). But on running the app on my connected android device I am getting following error in Android Monitor

> I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used.

I have no idea how to resolve this error.

Comment: may this will help you : https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/#add-gtm-to-project

Comment: can you share screen shot of error?

Comment: use this example https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/37489790/5746625

Comment: I have tried this and type the mentioned adb commands in this link in command prompt but nothing happens although I have connected my device