# Firebase authentication has stopped working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I can no longer log in to my app through Firebase Authenticator, I haven't changed the code one bit and it has been working perfectly up untill now. I have previously registered users and have been able to log in with them so I am unsure why all of a sudden it stops working?

In my LogCat I am getting this error:

> adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app
>   com.example.finalyearproject 2019-11-18 15:21:27.064 8115-8169/? I/FA:
>   Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used 2019-11-18
>   16:21:43.915 3260-3276/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database
>   '/data/user/0/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/databases/icing-mdh.db'
>   was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in
>   progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer
>   needed. 2019-11-18 16:24:11.250 3018-4319/com.google.android.gms
>   W/FA-SVC: Interrupted in onRunTask while uploading 2019-11-20
>   15:18:51.122 3260-9826/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used 2019-11-20
>   15:19:00.522 3260-9097/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
>   W/PairHttpConnection: Could not get EndOfData, throwing '65545'
>       com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.o.e: Error code: 656391 | Error code: 656385

**I am also getting this error in my Run:**

> D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
>   W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed;
>   errno=13 (Permission denied)
>
> W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:38): avc: denied { write } for
>   name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=7420
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768
>   tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
>   app=com.example.finalyearproject

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478505/using-google-analytics-with-firebase-google-tag-manager-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

Try this

```
adb shell kill <PID>
```

or Check

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:[latest-version]'
}
```

or check firebase-ui or firebase version.

Comment: Hi, 
Where should I write or try the "adb shell kill <PID>".

 Also when I have tried to implement that I get this error: Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:[latest-version].