# ADB logcat log entries are truncated - how to achieve the full log message?

Tags: android, adb, logcat, bluestacks

In the use case, I was trying to debug the data tracking using ADB (Android Debug Bridge) and BlueStacks 5. To reproduce the issue, here are the steps:

1. open BlueStacks 5 and enable ADB setting; open the target app
2. `adb kill-server` -> `adb start-server`
3. `adb connect localhost:5556` (the port is in BlueStacks 5 setting)
4. `adb devices` (only one device allowed, and will be listed in the console; show `offline` if connection failed)

for debugging firebase apps

1. `adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE`
2. `adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE`
3. `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app [app identifier]`
4. `adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC`

The commands above are all necessary to debug an app.

I understand the terminal has limited line output, but I have yet to find a way or adb command to avoid truncated output. I've tried to output it to a txt file, but it remained the same. Since I am not a developer of the app, is there any way to achieve the complete logs?
[image]

Comment: @Robert Thanks. It's weird since my commands are logcat-related. I'll take a look at rooting and try to see if my smartphone leads to incomplete logs.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your post. You ware asking to get the complete log output instead of the truncated log entry. Logcat limits the maximum message size. So as far as I know you can not increase this limit, only the limit for the logcat ringbuffer where all messages are saved, but that doesn't affects the individual maximum message size. So the only easy way I see is using Frida and hook all the Log functions and then print the arguments.

Comment: The fastest approach for you would be using `frida-trace` with the trace argument `-j android.util.Log!*` to get all calls that end up in logcat.

Comment: @Robert, I appreciate it! I'll post an answer after trying the `Frida.`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that might be helpful in that it only shows the event I want, meaning the logging message won't be truncated. In BlueStack5, there's a command `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.bluestacks.home` for activating faster debug mode event logging. Additionally, I enable Google Analytics with Firebase through another StackOverFlow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37478505/using-google-analytics-with-firebase-google-tag-manager-android-sdk).

Therefore, the commands:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb connect localhost:5556
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <app-identifier>
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.GoogleTagManager VERBOSE
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.bluestacks.home
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC GoogleTagManager
```